# How to pass simulation information to a simulated device that uses a generic interface?

Tags: c#, simulation

Currently, I am developing a software in C# (.NET 6) that tests devices after production. Therefore, it runs specific tests, e.g., voltage measurements, using the connected hardware. If the voltages are not in the expected range, the tested device will fail.

I implemented the voltage measurements using a generic IVoltMeter interface. This interface has a VoltMeter implementation for the hardware device, and a VoltMeterSimul implementation for simulated runs (necessary for development). Both implement the IVoltMeter interface and the corresponding method Measure().

In order to be able to simulate proper runs, I want to be able to return pre-configured measurement values for Measure() if VoltMeterSimul is used. The problem is that these values have to be different for each measurement instance, and also be in the proper range, or else the measurement will be rated fail and the test run will be stopped. But Measure() is a function that is identical for each call, so VoltMeterSimul will not be able to distinguish between different calls.

I came up with two solutions for this problem:

1. Change the signature of Measure() to Measure(string simulationId). For VoltMeterSimul, I can now distinguish between different Measure calls and define simulated values as appropriate, while for the real device VoltMeter, the parameter simulationId will be ignored. But it seems like a bad code smell to implement a parameter in the interface that is only used for simulation purposes and not for the real productive mode.
2. Provide VoltMeterSimul with a pre-defined list of values that have to be returned for subsequent Measure calls. This removes the dependency of an otherwise superfluent parameter like in 1), but since there are a lot of Measure calls, the proper handling can get confusing. Moreover, this method fails if the schedule of measurements is not known strictly in advance, e.g. if a measurement has to be repeated or is omitted under certain runtime conditions.

Is there a better option? I'd probably prefer 1) over 2), but I am not happy with both.

Comment: I suspect that real voltage values change over time, otherwise, you would not need to call Measure() multiple times. How is this time represented in your code? Are there just some `await Task.Delay` here and there or do you use another technique, for example a scheduler?

Comment: You've lost your way on the abstraction to the point where you rely on the method being called at the right cadence for it to even work properly. This requires ground up redesign. Explain what values you need. Explain what should happen when you skip a measurement. Think of it like a radio vs a cassette player. If I turn a radio off for 5 min and back on again, the broadcast will have continued. If I turn a cassette player off for 5 min and on again, the playback will have paused and will resume from where you left off. I suspect you need the radio approach here, but that requires confirmation

Comment: @pschill Voltages don't change over time. Different things are measured using different relays. I switch on relay A and measure the voltage, then switch off relay A and switch on relay B and measure the voltage, and so on. But the voltage meter itself is always the same.

Comment: @Flater The software is part of a test stand that has a (mostly) fixed cadence of actions and measurements. Each measurement must be in the given limits or the device under test is rated fail. Changeing the cadence of measurement is not allowed, except for very specific cases (some measurements are allowed to be repeated if the result is close to the limits but not inside).

Comment: @Thern: Are you talking from the perspective of your business logic, or your consumer? There's a big difference between the two. If the latter, it's irrelevant for what my previous comment focused on, since the business logic itself does not factor in the cadence. If the former, it seems better to model this with push updates instead of putting the onus on the consumer to poll at an arbitrary rate set by the business logic. Based on the fact that you are using a polling approach, I infer that the cadence is set by the consumer, not the business logic.

Comment: @Flater I'm not polling anything. I have a test run agenda that is separated into single test steps. These steps are performed in a pre-defined order, but some test steps can be omitted or repeated depending on the result of previous test steps. I don't need any push updates for this.

Answer (score 2):

You describe doing voltage measurements on a hardware device that should generally result in a sequence of different voltages, but where sometimes a measurement needs to be repeated.

You don't describe what causes the hardware device to provide different voltages, but most likely you also have a way in your software to cause the correct conditions for a measurement run to exist.

A good simulation would implement 2 interfaces: `IVoltMeter` *and* the interface used by the software to set the correct conditions for reading a particular voltage back. The simulation class would then, in a simplified way, convert the input conditions into a voltage to be measured.

Comment: "You don't describe what causes the hardware device to provide different voltages" - true, but measurement results are not directly related to the hardware device. I have a test stand that switches relays for measuring different properties. After switching a relay, I measure. Then another relay is switched, and I measure again.

Comment: @Thern, then your simulation should know about the status of those relays and respond accordingly.

Comment: That is indeed an idea, similar to what Simon Lehmann's answer pointed out. However, in this case I now have to introduce a new relay status storage I don't need for production, and I generate a dependency between the relay board and the voltmeter that was not part of the software up to now (although indeed this dependency matches the real situation).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, you don't want to introduce simulation-only related aspects into your production/business interfaces. You already mention that concern and I fully agree with that. The problem is, that it burdens the actual business logic with the "simulationId" or "runId" concept, which may or may not be of value for the real thing. You then have to think about how and where these values are generated and how you know them in advance to set up your simulation accordingly. In addition, it introduces the very real potential for having people "abuse" that in the actual implementation for something that it wasn't intended for (source: it happened on one of my projects).

You also mention that you feel the need for the simulation to be able to react dynamically to different situations ("if a measurement has to be repeated or is omitted under certain runtime conditions"). This can mean two things:

1. the simulation is intended to be used in interactive/exploratory testing.
2. the automated tests are ill defined as they do not fully control what is supposed to happen.

For the interactive scenario, you usually have to actually implement a *simulation* of the hardware system, at least to the degree necessary for it to appear "real" enough. That usually means to have simulations for all hardware interfaces (e.g. switches, relays, sensors, etc.) and these simulations may have to interact with each other (e.g. a simulated sensor needs to know the state of the simulated relay to simulate different voltages). For simple systems, this may only require minimal configuration and no interaction with the simulation at runtime. More often than not, you want a separate UI for the simulation to see what is being simulated and control it separately.

For the automated test scenario, you really need to define each test case and set up the environment accordingly to what you expect. You have to eliminate any randomness or your tests will be "flaky". That means you have to get, e.g. time under control and design/adapt the interfaces to the system under test and you simulation such that you can put it into a defined state from which you can start the test. For example, you mention "if a measurement has to be repeated": there must be defined conditions when this happens, so you have to set up the system in advance that this either happens or does not happen in a particular test case. There is no need to react dynamically to that in the simulation then.

It is possible to design and use the simulation components for both scenarios and also to have some more dynamic automated tests where you give up some control. I would say the value of those kind of tests is questionable, though.

Comment: I understand your idea. The disadvantage is that I presently don't care about the relay status in the software, so instead of an unused parameter in the interface, I would have an otherwise unused status storage function that is only necessary for simulation purposes. Moreover, I create a new dependency inside the software only for simulation, since my voltmeter now depends on the relay board and its status. And that is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Thern No, these dependencies are only between the simulation implementations, not between the actual production implementations. Of course you have to set up the simulation components and their dependencies somewhere, but that is necessary in any case and can be usually done quite easily by using a DI container.

Comment: This is only correct if all components are simulated or none. But in my case, each component can be simulated or not. So in the case of a simulated multimeter and a real relay board, I need the real relay board to write the status to the simulated multimeter. Or do I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do 1 is change the signature to `Measure(string runId)` so the calling code doesn't have to know if it's a simulation. When you measure this thing you must be driving it some how. Be nice to have a way to correlate drive runs with measurement runs.

As for 2, well that's just part of 1. Because what you've really been calling is `voltMeter.Measure(id)`. Now only `voltMeter` knows if this is a simulation. If it is it can use `id` to map it's results according to how you built it:

```csharp
IVoltMeter voltMeter = new VoltMeterSimul(measurementMap);`
```

If it's not then `id` is just a way to report what run these measurements came from. Thus `Measure` is called the same way. but `voltMeter` is constructed differently:

```csharp
IVoltMeter voltMeter = new VoltMeter(device);`
```

By keeping knowledge of the simulation isolated very little code is aware of it.

Of course you could do all this with the device instead.

Comment: I don't see the difference between "string runId" and "string simulationId" except for the naming. In both cases, this parameter will only be used for the simulation and not for the proper device.

Comment: I explicitly said to use it for the proper device. It’s how you mark which run is happening.